# Network Data Optimization for Windows-based VPN

Tags: optimization, vpn, compression

I am looking for ways to embed compression in a VPN setup so that users connecting from mobile devices to the VPN server will be able to decrease their bandwidth consumption and save up on their data plans.

Does anyone know of a good proprietary/opensource package that I can deploy on servers to compress the traffic? Most of the links I got were both client/server based i.e data was compressed on the server side and decompressed on the client side. This, of course, cannot work in my case as the client side wont be under my control.